# Angular 2+, using ngClass to float right to left with slow transition speed

Tags: css, angular, css-transitions

Using Angular 2+

I'm trying to get a label to float left to right and back depending on a boolean value (that changes on a click of a button)

This works:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="title-text" [ngClass]="myBoolValue ? 'float-right' : 'float-left'">SomeText</label>
</div>
```

However, adding a transition to make it float slowly doesn't work.
I tried using my own classes that have **1.5sec transition speed**, instead of bootstraps default **"float-right"** & **"float-left"** here:

```
.f-right {
    transition : all 1.5s ease;
    float: right;

}


.f-left {
    transition : all 1.5s ease;
    float: left;
}
```

Still not working slowly, any idea why, any suggestion?

Comment: Float can not be animated with CSS only. Instead use position absolute or relative and set left =0 or right =0

Comment: If you're animating horizontally do not use float, which cannot be animated, use `transform: translateX`.